# matplotlib:line chart to show all products price on each date with matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

how to use line chart to show all products price on each date in one chart?

the dataframe has three columns and is like:

```
+---------+-------+----------+
| product | price |   date   |
+---------+-------+----------+
| pen     |     1 | 20190101 |
| apple   |     2 | 20190101 |
| book    |     3 | 20190101 |
| cup     |     4 | 20190101 |
| pen     |   0.8 | 20190102 |
| apple   |   2.2 | 20190102 |
| book    |   3.1 | 20190102 |
| cup     |   3.5 | 20190102 |
| pen     |   0.6 | 20190103 |
| apple   |   2.6 | 20190103 |
| book    |   2.1 | 20190103 |
| cup     |   4.3 | 20190103 |
+---------+-------+----------+
```

[image]

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: @sentence please check if this is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'product':['pen','apple','book','cup','pen','apple','book','cup','pen','apple','book','cup',],
                   'price':[1,2,3,4,0.8,2.2,3.1,3.5,.6,2.6,2.1,4.3],
                   'date':['20190101','20190101','20190101','20190101','20190102','20190102','20190102','20190102','20190103','20190103','20190103','20190103']})
```

you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group products and [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/contents.html) to plot prices for each product:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in df.groupby('product'):
    plt.plot(i[1].date,i[1].price,'-o',label=i[0])

plt.legend(loc='upper center',
           bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.2),
           fancybox=True,
           shadow=True,
           ncol=4)
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.show()
```

[image]